# Tiny/no output from CMOY headphone amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, headphones, ne5532

I've built this little amp around the classic CMOY design, but don't seem to be getting any output except for a tiny distorted signal, in both unity and with 10 kΩ resistor position on the relay.

If I bypass the input caps the signal does seem better, but possibly still a little distorted. The caps are definitely fine.

I've used this basic design before with the only difference being the single sided PSU and the relay to vary the feedback.

Any help solving the issue would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This needs a symmetric power supply.

Comment: Or at least a ~6V bias.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I tried biasing the input with 50k resistors to Vcc at the junction with R1/R2. Still not unity gain (or unity-ish) but definitely improved. Could you suggest a better method so as to avoid the dual rail solution? Thanks

Comment: You also have to pull R5 and R6  to a midpoint.  You can replace each 1K resistor to ground with a 2K to 12V and a 2K to ground to preserve your gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your power rails are 12V and GND, and your inputs are biased to GND.  As such, your inputs will typically be either outside of, or occasionally just within, their limits.  Your op amp isn't rail to rail input range; at +/-15V power, it could have as little as +/-12V dynamic range.  I wouldn't count on more than 3-9V at 12V.  (A rail to rail op amp would help a lot here.)

The bottom line is, add a negative supply or bias the inputs to 6V.  There's multiple options for that:

1. You can add a 3rd op amp, direct negative feedback and a divider on the + input at 6V.  R1, R2, R5, and R6 can then be connected to 6V instead of GND.
2. You can replace each of R1, R2, R5, and R6 with dividers of resistors double their current value (200K for R1/2 and 2K for R5/6).  Each divider should have a resistor going to 12V and a second going to GND.

You might also consider an op amp designed for a lower operating voltage, and think about one with rail-to-rail performance if you want more than 6VP-P out.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just one further question, would those values in scenario 2 also be fine for a 24v single rail? They 12v in the schema is just for the relay and vcc is actually 24v. Thanks

Comment: That would probably work significantly better, actually.